# VBA Editor Data type mismatch

Tags: vba, types, mismatch

I keep getting a "data type mismatch" when running this in access 2007,

I've been looking at it for a while and cannot figure it out.

```
Private Sub Combo7_AfterUpdate()
    Dim clString As Integer
    clString = Me![Combo7].Value
    strSQL = "SELECT [Categorized Tables].[Name of Table] " & _
             "INTO [catTemp] " & _
             "FROM [Categorized Tables] " & _
             "WHERE [Categorized Tables].[Category] = " & clString
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

The debugger points to the DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL line.

Anyone have an Idea of where I am  going wrong?

Comment: Try this `clString = Val(Me![Combo7].Value)`

Comment: @Siddharth You should post this as an answer instead.

Comment: @JP.: Yup I can or if the user wants he/she can post that as an answer and accept it as well :)

Comment: OK but it's your answer, you should get credit for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by Siddharth Rout:

"Try this     `clString = Val(Me![Combo7].Value)`"